# JPA AttributeConverter for LocalDateTime

Tags: hibernate, date, jpa, converters

I'm closely following these posts (https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/, https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/jpa21converter) to implement converter from JPA 2.1 sql.Timestamp to LocalDateTime and vice-versa.

However, it looks like my conveter doesn't work. It seems it is never called as sysout doesn't print out anything.

This is my converter:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp>{

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        System.out.println("CONVERTER TIMESTAMPS: " + localDateTime);
        return (localDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        System.out.println("CONVERTER TIMESTAMPS: " + timestamp);
        return (timestamp == null ? null : timestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }

}
```

This is entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = Generationtype.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    ...
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    /*I also tried here: @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class))*/
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    ...
}
```

This is my method in may DAO class:

```
TypedQuery<Question> query = em.createQuery("SELECT q FROM Question q", Question.class);
query.getResultList().forEach(question -> {
    LOGGER.info("{}|{}|{}", question.getId(), question.getDescription(), question.getCreatedAt());
});

return query.getResultList();
```

This prints out:

```
1|hello|null
2|hi|null
3|howdy|null
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got it working now. I removed

> transient

from

```
private transient LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

SonarLint is requiring it since the class implements Serializable that's why I put it at first.

Comment: Yeah. I missed it out.

Comment: How do you expect someone to help you out if you don't post the actual code?

Comment: I just tried to be careful enough coz of confidentiality. I can't post the actual code. I even replaced class names. My bad I excluded 'transient'.

Comment: Btw, thank you (you might have started doing effort to answer this question before I figured it out).